# How do I determine the category with the highest count within a group?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count

```
select substr(shopabb, 1, 4) as shopgroup, count(*)
from table
where shopabb like'h%'
group by substr(shoppabb, 1, 4)
order by count(*) DESC;
```

I'm counting all the shop abbreviations from my table in substring groups. I have another column called city that shows where the shop abbreviations are located. Now I also want to select/show the city where the substring group most often occurs and if possible also the count of the shopabb in this city. The result should look like that:

```
    shopabb   Count(*)   City      Count_City
    -----------------------------------------
   hel         50         London    40
   heal        20         Berlin    15   
   hot         10         Rome       8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()` with two levels of aggregation:

```
select shopgroup, sum(cnt) as total_count, 
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then city end) as city_with_max,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then cnt end) as cnt_at_max
from (select substr(shopabb, 1, 4) as shopgroup, city, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by substr(shopabb, 1, 4) order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from table
      where shopabb like'h%'
      group by substr(shopabb, 1, 4), city
     ) t
group by shopgroup
order by sum(cnt) DESC;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8b7425a94364d57c98fbe38163bd57ec) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the syntax works.

EDIT:

You can do this without window functions, but it is much more cumbersome:

```
select substr(shopabb, 1, 4) as shopgroup, city, count(*) as cnt
from table t
where shopabb like'h%'
group by substr(shoppabb, 1, 4), city
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from table t2
                   where substr(t2.shopabb, 1, 4) = substr(t.shopabb, 1, 4)
                   group by city
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

Note that this will return duplicates if two cities ties for the max.  It requires a bit more work to get the overall total as well.

Comment: [09:37:54] Error while executing SQL query on database 'table': near "(": syntax error.  I think the bracket before partition by is the problem.

Comment: @remotesatellite . . . The syntax error is caused by YOUR use of `table` to refer to your table.  Put in YOUR table name.  I just used what you provided in the question.

Comment: I replaced all the column names and also the table name. But I still get the same syntax error.

Comment: SQLite has supported window functions since version 3.25.0.  The current version is 3.32.  Perhaps you are using an older version.

Comment: I'm using 3.22.0. That should explain the problem.

Comment: I'm using now SQlite with 3.31.1 and I still get the error 'near "(": syntax error'. In your created query you only accessing the two columns  'shopabb' and 'city' correct?

Comment: @remotesatellite . . . I fixed two typos and added a db<>fiddle showing that at least the syntax works.

Comment: Now both examples are working. In the second example there is a comma too much after 'as cnt' in the first row. Thank you very much for your help. Appreciate it .